# Image cropping with PIL does not crop as expected on remote windows desktop

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-imaging-library

I am new to python any help is appreciated.I have developed a script in python using selenium webdriver which generates report and takes snapshot from the website. I have tested it on other peoples laptop its cropping properly .But when i deployed it in remote desktop(windows)  and ran it cropping got messed up.

> I have pasted code here .I am using two elements from flex taking
>   those point as reference point i have defined crop points so somehow i
>   am not hard coding the point.

```
element=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="LineChart"]')))
location = element.location
size = element.size
height_header=size['height']
top_wan=top = location['y']
element=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,'chartContainer')))
location = element.location
size = element.size
        driver.save_screenshot(fold_path+'\\Reports\\Screenshots\\LAN_traffic_by_apps_bidir'+str(x)+'_for_ref_site_'+str(ref_site)+'.png') # saves screenshot of entire page. 

im=Image.open(fold_path+'\\Reports\\Screenshots\\LAN_traffic_by_apps_bidir'+str(x)+'_for_ref_site_'+str(ref_site)+'.png')
left = location['x']
top = location['y']+ 3 *height_header + 4
right = location['x'] + size['width']
bottom= location['y'] + 25 *height_header - 2
height_all_row=size['height']
im = im.crop((left, top, right, bottom)) # defines crop points
```

Comment: what is happening exactly?

Comment: with above code when i run script in my system it crops graph out of webpage very clearly even in my colleagues laptop . I have developed UI to triger this script . So i deployed it on remote windows machine there cropping is not as expected. Means it is going sometimes above and below but left and right positions are as expected.